# How to Zoom out Lock Screen Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

[image][image][image]
How can i zoom out the lock screen which wrongly zoom in . I donot how. Please help me out.

Comment: Consider moving this to https://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hover your mouse on the upper right corner of the window. You will see a down caret icon.
[image]

From this dropdown menu just turn off zoom option.